# In the following code is it possible to convert long datatype into string datatype?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - Convert number to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071040/java-convert-number-to-string)

```
private String getHome() {
    String defaultHome = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); 

    File f = new File("/sdcard/download");

    File[] files = f.listFiles();

   for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        File file = files[i];
        //take the file name only
    long size = file.length()/1024;
    String path = file.getPath().substring(file.getPath().lastIndexOf("/")+1,file.getPath().length()).toLowerCase(); 
    String newString = size.toString();



    //String path = getSharedPreferences(PREF_TAG, 0).getString(PREF_HOME,defaultHome);
    //if (path.length()>1 && path.endsWith("/")) {
    //  path = path.substring(0,path.length()-2);
    //}


    //File pathFile = new File(path);

    if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory())
        return path+size;
    else
        return defaultHome+size;
    }
   return defaultHome;
}
```

Comment: Well, *is* it possible? What have you tried? Did it work? If not, why not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563608/check-whether-a-string-is-parsable-into-long-without-try-catch , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121923/i-cant-convert-string-to-int , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653990/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-int-to-a-string , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604379/is-using-int-bad-for-converting-java-ints-to-strings

Comment: The related questions have to do with "int", but it's the *exact same thing*. Consider that 99% of the post is *irrelevant* to actually answering the question. Only include what is relevant: I can't even see *which* part needs the conversions.

Answer (score 1):

You may convert value of long type to String type using `String.valueOf()` or `Long.toString()` method.

```
String str1=String.valueOf(long_var);
String str2=Long.toString(long_var);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
long size = f.length()/1024;
String s = String.valueOf(size);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
String newString  = String.valueOf(size);
```

or simply u can do `String newString  = size+"";`

See for the [doc in this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: By now, you should have editing right. I suggest editing your post next time.

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman: Thanks for specifying.In future, Will be careful before posting. :)